# No output from my C# calculator

Tags: c#

I can run the program and fill in my inputs but get no output.No errors at all.
I am making an calculator that works by selecting radio buttons to select a mathematical function.
The answer must apear in the tbAntwoord but I cant get that working
Can somebody please help>? Its a school assignment and I am really new to this

```
private void buBereken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //variabelen
        double antwoord;
        int x, y, graden;

        //inlezen variabelen
        antwoord = Convert.ToInt16(tbAntwoord.Text);
        x       =  Convert.ToInt16(tbX.Text);
        y       =  Convert.ToInt16(tbY.Text);
        graden  =  Convert.ToInt16(tbGraden.Text);

        // berekeningen
        if (raDelen.Checked)
            antwoord = x / y;

        if (raMacht.Checked)
            antwoord = Math.Pow(x, y);

        if (raSin.Checked)
        antwoord = (Math.Sin(graden));

        if (raCos.Checked)
            antwoord = (Math.Cos(graden));

       tbAntwoord.Text = antwoord.ToString();
       Console.Write("antwoord");
```

Comment: This question is not well formed or tagged.  The tag is particularly unhelpful in attracting a suitable audience.  You might consider tagging with the programming language used. Tell us what you expect the code to do, and what it actually does (especially as the symbol names and comments are not English.  The title needs to reflect the the problem you are having.  The conversational "forum style" is unnecessary and not appropriate to SO which is as much about building a Q&A repository as it is in solving your specific issue.

Comment: Where do you think `Console.Write` will send its output?

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating a value and assigning it to a variable `antwoord`, but you are printing a string `"antwoord"` rather then the variable:

```
Console.Write( antwoord ) ;
```

Even then, if your application has no console (a text-only window), there will be nothing to see the output on.

You are also setting the `Text` property of `tbAntwoord` to a string representation of `antwoord`, but it is not demonstrated in the code what `tbAntwoord` is.  For it to be displayed, it must refer perhaps to a object in the GUI form, or something else must specifically display it.  It cannot be determined from this fragment alone what the problem is.